# What is the meaning of a parentheses followed with exclamation point when opening and closing a parameter in an Asp.Net web control

Tags: asp.net, aspdotnetstorefront

In reference to the `ImageUrl` parameter in the following code:

```
        <asp:ImageMap ID="CheckoutMap" runat="server" ImageUrl="(!~/App_Themes/skin_(!SKINID!)/images/step_2.gif!)">
            <asp:RectangleHotSpot Bottom="54" HotSpotMode="Navigate" NavigateUrl="~/shoppingcart.aspx?resetlinkback=1&amp;checkout=true"
                Right="87" />
        </asp:ImageMap>
```

Comment: Looks like the control or attribute value is tokenized and intended for further processing. It doesn't correspond to any URL format I've seen in ASP.Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are skin tokens specific to ASP Dot Net Storefront.  Here is a link to the manual - http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-489-skin-tokens.aspx

Comment: Thank you, Wade. I am using ML Multistore, so this explains why I couldn't find it in the manual.